# ComboBox FindString Contains

Tags: vb.net

I have such entries in Winforms ComboBox:

```
Font 8 pt
Font 9 pt
Font 10 pt
Font 12 pt
Font 14 pt
```

Then I have search string " 9 ".
Is here native way to find index by search string without looping?

I try this:

```
Dim a As Integer = myComboBox.FindString(" 9 ", 0)
```

... but without good result.

Comment: Why do you assume that `ComboBox.FindString` doesn't use a loop? Here is the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,b1404c5a7b1038ed

Comment: I don't understand your question fully but I mean that I havent to write loop in order to find contained string. So I search for possible native metohod which may find contained string in combo entries. Showed code allways returns -1.

Comment: No, there is no native method in the franmework. You have to write your own. For example the one that i've shown below. However, note that it's not fail-safe. Consider that you have an item `Font 11 pt` and you search for `1`. You'll find the the first that contains 1.

Comment: That is why number in string have spaces before and after it. So " 1 " and " 11 " can't be the same in mean of searching.

Comment: But even if there was a "native" method available already in the framework(what is not the case), it would search sub-strings and not "words" (whatever it is, consider that there are also other word-delimiters like `',', '.', '!', '?', ';', ':', ' ', '-', '/', '\\', '[', ']', '(', ')', '<', '>', '@', '"'` etc.). So the simple answer to your question is: No, there is no native way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no, there is no available method in the framework that searches for sub-string in combobox items and returns the index of the first item which contains the search parameter.

But even [`ComboBox.FindString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8179s15(v=vs.110).aspx) uses a loop as you can see [in the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ListControl.cs,b1404c5a7b1038ed).

So there is nothing bad in using one, you could write an   extension method for this:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static int FindSubStringIndex(this ComboBox combo, string subString, StringComparison comparer = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
    {
        // Sanity check parameters
        if(combo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("combo");
        if (subString  == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < combo.Items.Count; index++)
        {
            object obj = combo.Items[index];
            if(obj == null) continue;
            string item = Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subString))
                return index;
            int indexInItem = item.IndexOf(subString, comparer);
            if (indexInItem >= 0)
                return index;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in this way:

```
int index = combo.FindSubStringIndex("9");
```

Whoops, VB.NET:

```
Public Module ControlExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function FindSubStringIndex(combo As ComboBox, subString As String, Optional comparer As StringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture) As Integer
        ' Sanity check parameters
        If combo Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("combo")
        End If
        If subString Is Nothing Then
            Return -1
        End If

        For index As Integer = 0 To combo.Items.Count - 1
            Dim obj As Object = combo.Items(index)
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Dim item As String = Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item) AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subString) Then
                Return index
            End If
            Dim indexInItem As Integer = item.IndexOf(subString, comparer)
            If indexInItem >= 0 Then
                Return index
            End If
        Next

        Return -1
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: OK Tim, thanks for this ADVANCED version :) but I searched for something minimalistic and "handy" in mean of programming, native function. That's why I said "without loopng".