# c# listbox live search

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am learning c# and I started by making some dummy app, with all elements I can practice in it. I have search text field and below I have a list box with items.

I tried with this code but I got result only if I start searching from the first letter. I want to be able to search by letters in between words.

Example: List Item: "0445110085"
If I start searching from "0445" I will get results but if I start with "5110" for example I got message item not found.

Below is my code,

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myString = searchBox.Text;
        int index = listBox1.FindString(myString, -1);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(index,true);
        }
        else 
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found!");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

regards :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search listbox for item containing a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267368/search-listbox-for-item-containing-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ComboBox FindString Contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904345/combobox-findstring-contains)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above two items because those are for different controls and/or frameworks.

Comment: Replace ComboBox with ListBox and the one I referenced works. User2012384's works as well. It is a duplicate for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the details of FindString,

*Finds the first item in the System.Windows.Forms.ListBox that **starts with**
the specified string.*

So you will have to custom write code to achieve it. Something like below,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myString = textBox1.Text;
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if(listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(myString))
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }                        
        if(!found)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item not found!");
        }                
    }
```

Comment: @AleksandarMilic You're welcome. Happy coding and learning !!

Comment: :D :D I hope I will be able to help to someone one day as you guys helping me today. Best regards

Comment: This solution has two problems. The first is minor and may be accepted by author (the classic search of this type works using **StartsWith** method not **Contains**). The second is that you are not checking the last item of the list so it will never be found.

Comment: @Seprum The OP wants to search for presence of his search text within the items in the listbox. How would StartsWith serve the purpose here ? FindString does that already but that was not the question. Secondly, all the items are verified till the end of the listBox untill a match is found. How do you say that last item will never be found ?

Comment: Look at this part: `i < listBox1.Items.Count - 1`. No need to subtract `1`.

Comment: i starts from 0, not from 1. ListBox has a zero based index. Please test the code once.

Comment: I have just tested it. You are wrong. Of course, it starts with `0` as every array in C#. Let's suppose your list has `3` elements. `Count` will be equal `3` then. When we are making condition like `i < Count - 1` the loop will be executed only `two` times with `i` equal to `0` and `1`. It's quite easy to understand.

Comment: @Seprum That's correct. I initially had it as `count` and the code I wrote also had the same. I left 'count - 1' but didn't add the '<=' operator. Same as having `count` alone. Edited now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use **StartsWith** method to check if specific item starts with string you have entered:

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string prefix = searchBox.Text;
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if(listBox.Items[i].ToString().StartsWith(prefix))
        {
            listBox.SelectedItem = listBox.Items[i];
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I got error on first key press. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Can you tell me what error are you recieving please?

Comment: Fixed. Try it now.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\shogy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4a\WindowsFormsApplication4\Form1.cs 55 48 WindowsFormsApplication4

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed again. Have no Studio right now :/

Comment: Emmanuel Ponnudurai attached the same code but with Contains instead of StartWith. With contains it works no metter what I type (start, middle, end) with startwith I got results only if I start from first character

Comment: Than you should give appropriate examples for what you want to recieve as result. Your example tells that **StartsWith** is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

for sure not the best solution, but it works

```
    List<string> search = new List<string>();
    List<string> listBoxItems = new List<string>();
    listBoxItems = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            search.Clear();
            listBoxItems.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (IsSubstring(textBox1.Text, x))
                {
                    search.Add(x);
                }
            });
            listBox1.DataSource = null;
            listBox1.DataSource = search;
        } 
        else
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = listBoxItems;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSubstring(string text, string x)
    {
        if (x.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()))
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```